# <input type="file" accept="image" /> Wont show up, yet it exists in the dom

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I can inspect element and see `<input type="file" accept="image" />`, it seems like the type="file" is causing the problem, when I remove it I can refresh and see the input box. I am wondering if this is a problem with angular 2 or if this is a problem with how I bootstrapped my application. This problem did not exist in previous iterations of angular 2, it only occurred within the last update to the "stable version" . I can post my component but there is nothing there but my selector and html reference . Any help appreciated to point me in the right direction to debug this! Thanks in advance

Comment: eliminate angular from the mix and test it: whip up a plain html page with that tag in it in both versions and see what happens.

Comment: im doing this right now. Using jsbin I can use this code with success <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form> Yet it simply wont show up in my component . I feel like my html is just borken for some reason

Comment: Are there any errors in your console when you try to open app? You can't expect people to help you if you don't post at least some code here. You have to provide as much information as possible, people can't read your mind.

Comment: OK wow, just solved it i feel like an idiot, i copied some scss for a form in a differnt component and loaded it into my base.scss . and inside was a input[type="file"] { display: none } ..... so yea haha im and idiot . Thanks for the help boys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had bad styling layered inside other components . I have much to learn